# C++ string and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string

If string is just an array of chars, then is it considered bad coding to directly access an index of a string? for example...

```
 string test = "Hello"; 
 cout << text.[0];

 int lenOfTest = (int)test.length();
 for(int i = 0; i < lenOfTest; i++ ){
   cout << test[i];
 }
```

Comment: This is fine, except for `text.[0]`, I guess that is some sort of typo

Comment: A `std::string` is not just an array of characters. It's a standard class, which overloads `[]` to access the elements of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::string` is **not** a simple array of `char`, although it is a *container* of `char`, and yes, you can access each of its elements normally. Just don't use the point before the open  `[` like you did in your second line.

Comment: The `std::string` does wrap an array of `char` though, which you have full access to.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, one would actually hope you don't have *full* access to the underlying buffer. If you look at libc++, for instance, there are two buffers, only one of which is actually in use for a given instance - I would hope users don't get to muck with either fully and directly

Comment: You can get it via `&s[0]`. To be clear I should say "full access to the contents of", I guess; you can't reallocate it .

Comment: you also shouldn't write to the memory pointed to by `&s[0]` (nor `c_str()` or `data()`...) because it's UB.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a bad practice to access a char element using the operator[], however keep in mind that accessing a character like this will not raise an exception in case a invalide position is being used. To raise an exception, use the `string::at`.